# Laravel getting last items from 2nd Level of nested array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, nested-loops

I am working with laravel framework and I have a nested array in which to display a subset of results. For example, on the array below I display multi task per year.

```
Array
(
  [0] => years_tasks_section_grid
    (
      [0] => 2022
      [1] => tasks_grid
        (
          [0] => Task1 2022
          [1] => Task2 2022
          [2] => Task3 2022
          [3] => Task4 2022
          [4] => Task5 2022
          [5] => Task6 2022
        )
    )

  [1] => years_tasks_section_grid
    (
      [0] => 2021
      [1] => tasks_grid
        (
          [0] => Task1 2021
          [1] => Task2 2021
          [2] => Task3 2021
        )
    )
)
```

**The problem I want to display the last 3 tasks from the 2nd level of nested array.** Basically, based on my example **I try to get this (only tasks of 2022)**:

```
[0] => Task1 2022
[1] => Task2 2022
[2] => Task3 2022
```

But I am getting this (Basically, I am getting both 3 last tasks 2022 and 2021 and probably I will have other tasks of the future years):

```
[0] => Task1 2022
[1] => Task2 2022
[2] => Task3 2022

[0] => Task1 2021
[1] => Task2 2021
[2] => Task3 2021
```

This is my code in Laravel blade (I used array_slice but is not working because I have the result as above):

```
@foreach($sections['years_tasks_section_grid'] as $year)
   @foreach(array_slice($year['tasks_grid'], 0, 5) as $task)
       <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-start mb-7 mb-xl-0 px-0">          
            // Other code
       </div>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you get data in array with integer as key , or can you customize it by adding proper string for key ? like `'year' => '2022' , 'tasks' => [ 0 => 'Task1 2022'` , because might helpful if you convert this array into collection and use its magic to filter and take limited data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `$counter`, initialized at 0 and wrap it around your `div`. First, let's create the variable:

```
@php
$counter = 1
@endphp
```

and now, let's wrap it around your div:

```
@foreach($sections['years_tasks_section_grid'] as $year)
   @foreach(array_slice($year['tasks_grid'], 0, 5) as $task)
       @if ($counter++ < 3)
       <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-start mb-7 mb-xl-0 px-0">          
            // Other code
       </div>
       @endif
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```